# How to know if file is referenced by DLL or project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In VS.NET 2010, how do you tell if a reference was added to a project by DLL or project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Project Reference will contain:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Project\Foo.csproj">
```

A DLL reference will contain:

```
<Reference Include="Foo.dll">
```

Comment: Ah, so you have to peek inside the .csproj file?

Comment: @4thSpace - It appears so.  I don't notice any difference between the two in the Solution Explorer.  Icons are the same, not really any signs in the Properties panel.  Odd.

Comment: @4thSpace - Though one difference, a referenced DLL will have a *Specific Version* property in the Properties Pane.  A referenced project does not have this property.